# shell script works, but not on boot. [Raspberry pi]

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, boot, autostart

I have a python script running on a raspberry pi.

I defined a `launcher.sh` file and trying it with `sh launcher.sh` runs the program

The file

```
cd /home/pi/Documents
PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
python3 /home/pi/Documents/myfile.py
```

I tried `chmod launcher.sh` and `sudo chmod 775 launcher.sh`

But when I start the launcher on boot, I get an error loged in cronlog:

> import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError No module named pandas

I do have two python versions on the Raspberry 3.9 and 3.10 (unfortunately not in an environment).

`pip list` gives me: `pandas 1.4.3`

`python --version`  gives me `Python 3.10.0`

`python3 --version`  also gives me `Python 3.10.0`

In `/home/pi/.local/lib/` I do have a python 3.10 and python 3.9 folder. Both have a pandas folder in the sitepackages.I just saw, that the pyhton3.9 folder also has a pandas-1.4.3dist.info folder (The python3.10 does not have that).

The crontab line is as follows:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

I don't get it...
is the python 3.9 folder somehow intercepting... But I do set the Pythonpath and trying to run with `sh launcher.sh` does work, so I wonder what is going wrong. Somehow the wrong python is used I guess.

Thanks for your help

Edit:
I renamed the `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9` to get rid of the sidpackage... but no change

Edit: I tried to change the priority of python 3.10 and 3.9 with

```
sudo update-alternatives --install $(which python) python $(readlink -f $(which python3.10)) 3
sudo update-alternatives --install $(which python) python $(readlink -f $(which python3.9)) 2
```

with no luck

Edit: added the python3 --version suggestion

Edit: Error message when trying to install pandas for python3.9
with `pyhton3.9 -m pip install pandas` See output below.

............**almost FINAL EDIT:**............

I deinstalled (purge) python like suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292504/how-to-make-a-complete-removal-of-python-3-9-in-ubuntu-16-04/1299815#1299815) and then reinstalled python3.10 via [this great link](https://itheo.tech/installing-python-310-on-raspberry-pi)
Unfortunattely while deinstalling, I guess also the python2.7 was deinstalled, resulting in a complete system failure on startup. -> Lost all hope at 3 o'clock at night ;-) And now resetting the sd-image starting all over.

I will update a last time when I got it running with the fresh image

**Thank you all so much for your interest and participation. I love this community**

............................................

```
> ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
> line 223, in _main
>     status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
> line 180, in wrapper
>     return func(self, options, args)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
> line 297, in run
>     session = self.get_default_session(options)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
> line 78, in get_default_session
>     self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
> line 88, in _build_session
>     session = PipSession(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py",
> line 248, in __init__
>     self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py",
> line 131, in user_agent
>     zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),   File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py",
> line 125, in linux_distribution
>     return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py",
> line 681, in linux_distribution
>     self.version(),   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py",
> line 741, in version
>     self.lsb_release_attr('release'),   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py",
> line 903, in lsb_release_attr
>     return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py",
> line 556, in __get__
>     ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py",
> line 1014, in _lsb_release_info
>     stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
>     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
>     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')'
> returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: What is the result of `python3 --version`

Comment: Its: Python 3.10.0

Comment: Can you install pandas for python3.9 as well ? I suspect that your python3 default is set to python3.9 and python default is set to 3.10

Comment: is there a way to specifically install pandas for a specific version?

Comment: You can invoke the specific python version to install a module  by `python3.9 -m  pip install module`. Unless you messed up your paths.

Comment: damn this just gives me a looong error message. Something about the wheel.. distro.py

Comment: Can you post the error

Comment: I added it as an edit. Otherwise it would be to long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247041/discussion-between-solenya-and-florida-man).

Comment: Maybe you can use systemd to start your script as a service? https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that contab runs applications as root and therefore the packages have to be installed with sudo

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

solved the problem.
Shoutout to [CoderMike](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/70731/codermike)

Comment: You can tell crontab which user to run as. But, default is root.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Would you tell that in the crontab file where I call @reboot ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a shabang in your script.

Usually scripts being executed through the cli require

execution permission : `chmod +x`.
and shabang `#!` at the beginning of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
cd /home/pi/Documents
PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
python3 /home/pi/Documents/myfile.py
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: True, I did not put it here while actually using it. Sry. But that did not change the outcome. However, I did not use -a , what does that do?

Comment: Sorry I made an error.. I corrected it.  Was the correct entry.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Comment: I see that you used env. Not `#!/usr/bin/bash`, is there an advantage? If so what?

Comment: the advantage is, if there aren't any binaries in your '/usr/bin/bash' then it will locate the binary utilizing your environment variable. This is extremely useful is systems that have high lockdowns on permissions. usually, systems disable users from accessing folders off of the root directory.. so the '#!/usr/bin/env bash' does not only have to apply to bash or python but any installed binary, as long as it's added to your PATH variable. hope this helps!